# ngClass Directive Conditional else or ? 'class1':'class2'

Tags: angular, typescript

i am actually trying this code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<button [ngClass]="{'btn': showDirectiveContent === false ? 'btn btn-danger': 'btn btn-success'}">
    <b *ngIf="!showDirectiveContent; else noServer">Display Details</b>
      <ng-template #noServer>
        <b>Hide Details!</b>
      </ng-template>
</button>
```

the *ngIf works very well,  i tried also [ngStyle]
 [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor:  i > 4 ? 'green':''
Directive also work well, sadly i fail at ngClass Directive, tried to google its only normal one, no directives :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<!-- class="btn" is common to both cases -->
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-danger': !showDirectiveContent, 'btn-success': showDirectiveContent}">
<!-- content -->
</button>
```

Explanation:

According to https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass the `ngClass` atttribute expects the following format, when using an object as the value:

> Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given
>   in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

Comment: so its the 3rd in the list <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element> so thats it. i should have to try those list next time, thanks :)